# VM73:49Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined in jsfiddle

Tags: angularjs, jsfiddle

I am trying to run an angularJS example in jsfiddle (ofcourse learning purpose)  getting below errors in console.

When I add this cdn for angular compatibility: 
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.6/angular.min.js

I seen below error.

> VM141 angular.min.js:6 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=myApp&p1=Error%3A%2…oudflare.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangular.js%2F1.5.6%2Fangular.min.js%3A21%3A19)

When I remove the external source, seen below error:

> VM93:45 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Concern:

1. Do I need to add external source for angular example? If yes then what will be the correct way to add external resource. (like, search a cdn for that api and add).

Here's the code snippet:

html:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
Your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-click="displayName();">
Hello {{$scope.name}}
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
$scope.displayName = function(){
alert("In right place");
$scope.name = "Name";
}
});
```

Here's the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/supdas87/my1juu4e/2/

Comment: Click on the java script setting button, select a framework and copy the link from cdn or something of that framework and load-type "No-wrap in body"

Comment: Does [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38351563/4927984) solved your problem?

Comment: Your code is running not mine!!  You have changed my code in your way.. What I was thinking is even if my code are logical no problem with that,.. then why it failed to run. @Mistalis

Comment: Updated my answer to exactly match your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added [`angular-1.0.1.js` file](https://code.angularjs.org/angular-1.0.1.js) to external resources (you just have to copy and paste the URL), and changed `{{$scope.name}}` by `{{name}}` on your HTML file. You do not have to write `$scope` when you use `{{` `}}`, it is implicit.

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g857ga19/) based on the code you provided.

*PS: I've added Angular 1.0.1, but of course you can use the version of Angular you want. You can see allreleases [here](https://code.angularjs.org/).*

---

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  Your name: <input type="text" ng-model="name" ng-click="displayName();">
  Hello {{name}}
</div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.displayName = function(){
    alert("In right place");
    $scope.name = "Name";
  }
});
```

Comment: What he needed was to know how to setup angularjs source file in jsfiddle, I  can't see you explained that here.

Comment: give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime :)

Comment: @JalalMostafa way to go haha